# Why $onInit method is not invoked in the example below?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I would like to use angular's component method, but it seems something is wrong. I have been double checking this code for a while. There is no typo, it seems it fits for the documentation, but, still, it is not working.

I have [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317578/about-angular-1-5-component-lifecycle-hooks), Angular 1.5.3 is installed.

There is no output on the console. According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and [this](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) blog entry I should see the "onInit" text.

The component's template is displayed correctly, and I can see the the template is loaded, but it seems the controller is not instantiated / fired.

My app is written in Typescript.

**The component**:

```
module sayusiando.dilib.spa {

    export class LeftHandMenuComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

        public transclude: boolean = false;
        public controller: Function = LeftHandMenuController;
        public controllerAs: string = "vm";
        public templateUrl: string = "app/layout/leftHandMenu/leftHandMenuTemplate.html";

    }

    angular
        .module("dilib")
        .component("dilibLeftHandMenu", new LeftHandMenuComponent());
}
```

**compiled code**:

```
var sayusiando;
(function (sayusiando) {
    var dilib;
    (function (dilib) {
        var spa;
        (function (spa) {
            var LeftHandMenuComponent = (function () {
                function LeftHandMenuComponent() {
                    this.transclude = false;
                    this.controller = spa.LeftHandMenuController;
                    this.controllerAs = "vm";
                    this.templateUrl = "app/layout/leftHandMenu/leftHandMenuTemplate.html";
                }
                return LeftHandMenuComponent;
            })();
            spa.LeftHandMenuComponent = LeftHandMenuComponent;
            angular
                .module("dilib")
                .component("dilibLeftHandMenu", new LeftHandMenuComponent());
        })(spa = dilib.spa || (dilib.spa = {}));
    })(dilib = sayusiando.dilib || (sayusiando.dilib = {}));
})(sayusiando || (sayusiando = {}));
```

**Layout template**:

```
<div>
    <dilib-left-hand-menu class="col-lg-2"></dilib-left-hand-menu>
</div>
```

**LeftHandMenuController**:

```
module sayusiando.dilib.spa {
    "use strict";

    export interface ILeftHandMenuController {
    }


    export class LeftHandMenuController implements ILeftHandMenuController {

        $onInit: Function = (() => {console.log("onInit");});


        static $inject = ["LeftHandMenuService"];
        constructor(leftHandMenuService: sayusiando.dilib.spa.ILeftHandMenuService) {

            console.log("con");
            this.leftHandMenuService = leftHandMenuService;

            //this.activate();
            console.log("construct");
        }

        activate() { //activate logic }

    }

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .controller('leftHandMenuController', LeftHandMenuController);

}
```

**Compiled controller code**:

```
var sayusiando;
(function (sayusiando) {
    var dilib;
    (function (dilib) {
        var spa;
        (function (spa) {
            "use strict";
            var LeftHandMenuController = (function () {
                function LeftHandMenuController(leftHandMenuService) {
                    this.$onInit = (function () { console.log("onInit"); });
                    console.log("con");
                    this.leftHandMenuService = leftHandMenuService;
                    //this.activate();
                    console.log("construct");
                }
                LeftHandMenuController.prototype.activate = function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    this.leftHandMenuService.getLeftHandMenu()
                        .then(function (result) {
                        _this.leftHandMenu = result;
                    });
                };
                LeftHandMenuController.$inject = ["LeftHandMenuService"];
                return LeftHandMenuController;
            })();
            spa.LeftHandMenuController = LeftHandMenuController;
            angular
                .module('dilib')
                .controller('leftHandMenuController', LeftHandMenuController);
        })(spa = dilib.spa || (dilib.spa = {}));
    })(dilib = sayusiando.dilib || (sayusiando.dilib = {}));
})(sayusiando || (sayusiando = {}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the $oninit in a wrong way. Here is the proper, well working code:

```
module sayusiando.dilib.spa {
    "use strict";

    export interface ILeftHandMenuControllerScope {

    }


    export class LeftHandMenuController implements ILeftHandMenuControllerScope {

        public leftHandMenu: Array<sayusiando.dilib.spa.IModuleContract>;

        static $inject = ["leftHandMenuService"];
        constructor(
            private leftHandMenuService: sayusiando.dilib.spa.ILeftHandMenuService) {

        }


        public $onInit = () => {

            this.leftHandMenuService.getLeftHandMenu()
                .then((result: Array<sayusiando.dilib.spa.IModuleContract>): void => {
                    this.leftHandMenu = result;
                });

        }

    }

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .controller('leftHandMenuController', LeftHandMenuController);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to missing dependency parameter list on the module definition. There is a difference in these two statements:

```
angular.module("dilib")
angular.module("dilib",[])
```

The first statement tries to access an existing module with name dilib, whereas the second statement tries to create a module dilib with no dependencies. I believe you are trying to create a new module, and hence will need the second format.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I don't think this is the problem. This component is part of a bigger application, where I use other components too. The reason why I did not come across this problem is that, I do not use the already existing components' controllers. So far, components build up the layout of the app.

Comment: Also, I don't see the use of ng-controller directive inside the layout template. Are you associating it to the template somewhere else?

Comment: I went through the documentation and there is no example where the controller invoked directly.

Comment: There is. At https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component, search for text ng-controller.